# Error 'Action not allowed' when running script to create trigger (Google Script)

Tags: javascript, function, google-apps-script, triggers

I need to add a trigger via a function as I have a spreadsheet which will be copied many times, and I understand that the triggers entered via the menu do not copy.

I have the following function I need to run when a form is submitted:

```
function sendFormMessage() {
var emailAddress = "d********@kkkk.com";
var subject = "Form has been submitted";
var message = "The hotel has submitted the form";
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}
```

So I have created a custom menu as follows:

```
function onOpen() {
SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
.createMenu('New Menu')
  .addItem('Form submit', 'createTrigger')
  .addToUi();
}
```

And this should then create the trigger I need:

```
function createTrigger(){
var trigger =ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendFormMessage").forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()).onFormSubmit().create();
}
```

When I run this however I get a 'Action not allowed' error.

Comment: Tested your code, it worked as expected: when using the menu item, it prompted for authorization, then created a trigger. Does the error occur in a new spreadsheet, or one that's been copied?

Comment: in both sadly. Could it be some kind of permissions issue?

Comment: This happens (as of 2021) when your sheet is newly created but empty. I've opened a bug with Google, you can star it to get it some traction...
[https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/197133159](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/197133159)